# Javascript: Is there a use case for ever changing the arguments array

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I was listening to Douglas Crockford's infamous JavaScript video series (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM) and he made a statement about being careful not to change the the extra 'arguments' array parameter to avoid "weird" things from happening.

So that made me curious: Is there every a reason where you might want to do this? I couldn't think of one other than maybe some self-modifying code trickery for obfuscation perhaps.

Comment: In my humble opinion, no. I have been writing JavaScript for eight years (professionally for two years) and I have never modified the `arguments` object.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the response. Maybe this "feature" might hopefully be removed in ES6 then. Immutable objects is the way to go it sounds like.